# Ruby on Rails persistently store Hash from CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, hash

I have a ruby script written which takes a CSV file and converts the input into a hash:

```
Culper = File.open('.\CulperCSV.csv')

culper_hash = {}

# set up culper code hash from provided CSV
CSV.foreach(Culper) do |row|
    number, word = row
    culper_hash[word] = number
end
```

and I am trying to make a Rails app using the script.

My question: How do I store the Hash persistently (or the CSV data so I can build the hash) so that I can minimize load times?

My thoughts:

1) Load the CSV data into a database (seed it) and each time I get a visitor on my site, do the above assignment into a hash but from the db. (not sure how to do this but I can research it).

or

2) Load the complete hash into the database (I think I would have to serialize it?) so that I can do just one fetch from the db and have the hash ready to go.

I am very new to building apps, especially in Rails so please ask questions if what I am trying to do doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you should go with 2nd approach. Here are steps to do that:
Setup new app:

```
rails new app_name
bundle install
rake db:create
```

Create Model:

```
rails g model model_name column_name:text
rake db:migrate
```

Open model_name.rb file and add the following line

```
serialize :column_name
```

Now all sets. Just run the your script to parse .csv file and store hash in db. Your column is now able to store the hash.

```
Culper = File.open('.\CulperCSV.csv')
# get the object from database
obj = ModelName.first

# set up culper code hash from provided CSV
CSV.each(Culper) do |row|
    number, word = row
    obj.column_name[word] = number
end
obj.save
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt & detailed response. I followed your directions but am confused on the last step, which is to actually load the db/model with my CSV values. I have tried just running my file as a script but then it can't connect to the db (uninitialized constant CulperKey...which is my model name) so then I tried putting my script into db/seeds.rb and running 'rake db:seed' and I get:  "undefined method `culper_hash' for nil:NilClass" where culper_hash is my column_name. Can you explain what I should be doing to populate the db & furthermore, how to access my hash once I do?

Comment: Please confirm, did you run the script in the project console ? If yes, then please **run "CulperKey"** before running script, if you are not using the rails console, then please open project console and run script there, method to open the project console, 1) `cd "path to project directory"` 2) `rails c` 3) `CulperKey` (establish database connection) 4) Run the your script

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of this option of running scripts from the rails console...so that's how you can establish a connection to the db and modify it manually. I solved the problem using a **rake task** and posted the steps I followed in a separate answer. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.csv` file seems to be already in your Rails app directory, so load times shouldn't be bad (unless it's really big). However, if that file isn't going to change and you need only a small piece of it at a time, then I would store that in your database.

Create a model/migration that corresponds to the data you have in the `.csv` file and then (after migrating the migration) run a script to parse the data from your `.csv` file to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem following the advice of @Kh Ammad: setting up a new app, creating a model for it, and marking my column serializable.

However, I had some problems with running the script to populate the model with the hash so instead, after some research, I created the rake task below:

```
#lib/tasks/import.rake
require 'csv'

task :import, [:filename] => :environment do

    culper_hash = {}

    Culper = File.open('.\CulperCSV.csv')

    CSV.foreach(Culper) do |row|
        number, word = row
        culper_hash[word] = number
    end

    # culper_hash == column_name
    obj = CulperDict.create(culper_hash: culper_hash)
    obj.save
end
```

and ran it with:

```
$ bundle exec rake import
```

and my model contained the entire hash table in one entry!

I used this article to figure out how to run a rake task:
[http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=212](http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=212/)

Specifically, the last comment on the page by Lauralee (posted on December 20th, 2012 at 8:47 am) who ran into a similar problem.